# Problem in visualizing tabular with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, page-breaking

I'm quite new to LaTeX (I've used it at university for some basic formulas and ready to use templates) and I'm getting again into it for graphics stuffs: I love its clearness.

I'm trying to make a tabular list of figures done with TikZ. Here my template:

```
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }

    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
            \draw blablabla
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \\
        Description 1 blabla
    \end{tabular}

    &

    ... and so on

\end{tabular}
```

I have 27 figures. I have no need for particular page numbers but I think that 9 images fit in 1 page.

The impagination seems broken: only 1 page and after 4 lines of figures (12 figures) it goes out of page.

I hope it's clear also without a screenshot -
what could it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tabular` can't be broken over multiple pages. You need to either use one of the multi-page replacements like `supertabular` or `longtable` or do it without the outer `tabular`. You could simply put `\hfill`s between the three inner `tabular`s per line. This would give you then `lcr` orientation and would allow for page breaks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you might also consider using the `subfig` package and make something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
} \\
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
} \\
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{something}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
} \\
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
} \\
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[Something]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This makes 2 pages of `tikz` boxes, with continuous caption numbering.